# How to solve $\log_{\frac{1}{3}}(\frac{3x-1}{x+2})>0$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

How to solve

> $$\log_{\frac{1}{3}}(\dfrac{3x-1}{x+2})>0$$

I am not sure how to solve it.

Comment: Hint $\log(\frac{a}{b}) = \log(a) - \log(b)$

Comment: @GoodMorningCaptain this only if numerator and denominator are both positive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$\log_{(1/3)}\left(\frac{3x-1}{x+2}\right)=-\log_{3}\left(\frac{3x-1}{x+2}\right)=\log_3\left(\frac{x+2}{3x-1}\right)>0.$$
Note that $\log_a t>0$ if and only if $t>1$ (when $a>1$).

Answer (score 0):

Note: 
$$\log_{\frac13}(k)>0 \text{ when } 0<k<1$$

So you want when:
$$0<\frac{3x-1}{x+2}<1$$
$$\to0^2<\frac{(3x-1)^2}{(x+2)^2}<1^2$$
$$\to0^2(x+2)^2<(3x-1)^2<1^2(x+2)^2$$
$$\to0<(3x-1)^2<(x+2)^2$$
Now continue this by finding all $x$ which satisfy:
$$(x+2)^2>(3x-1)^2\text{ AND } (3x-1)^2>0$$